# Fieldsource query for droptree field

Tags: sitecore-query, fieldtype

Is it possible to use query for Droptree field in Sitecore 8.1?
In a multisite solution, I would like to point Droptree field source to an item in that particular site. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

Yes is possible to have a query source like

```
query:./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templatename='Site']/Data/Components/*
```

Have a look on this link how to use sources for fields: 
http://sitecore.wonderamy.com/2011/03/using-source-property.html